# Facebook create ad page doesn't show my og images, What did I wrong?

Tags: facebook, github, dns, facebook-opengraph, scraper

I created a github page and I have a custom domain for it. I used og meta tags in the head like:
`<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/images/myfacebook.png"/>`

Facebook debugger tool usualy returns response code 302, but on the fourth, fifth time it gets through with code 200, and recognizes everything fine. (don't know why)

But when I try to create a facebook ad here: https://www.facebook.com/ads/create/ my image never loads, I always get a small picture with a facebook camera icon. I know I could upload an image manually, but when I upload the png transparency turns to white. Anyway it should work, and it really annoys me.

I set up my domain records by the github pages help.

Comment: I think the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885695/why-is-my-github-hosted-site-responding-with-http-302-instead-of-200